# Time aggregating functions on Redis

Tags: redis, aggregate-functions

I would like to do an aggregate function on Redis 
that is time/timestamp-based.

Right now I am storing count of the events per key and a timestamp.
I would like to do an aggregation to pull how many counts have been incurred in particular time interval (e.g. in moths of June and July).

With SQL this would be something like:

`select count(*) from events
 where event_timestamp BETWEEN '2013-06-01 23:55:00'::timestamp
                 AND '2013-07-31 23:55:00'::timestamp;`

What would be the way to do this in Redis, if possible?

Comment: Provided you have indexed your data properly, you could write a server-side Lua script to calculate the aggregation. Or you can retrieve the raw data, and calculate the aggregation on client-side. Note that Redis is not designed for accumulating data and calculate analytics on them. Most other NoSQL solutions will likely be better for such use case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using zadd, zrange queries in redis :

> ZADD events event_1 "timestamp1"
>
> ZADD events event_1 "timestamp2"

Query them as:

> zrange events "timestamp1" "timestamp2"